Adjusting Footnote Indentation While Preserving Layout
I would like to remove the indentation from the footnotes, but when I use \usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}, I encounter issues with \footnotelayout{m}. However, if I remove \footnotelayout{m}, the footnotes adhere to the column format (see image 2). I would like to maintain the current format (see image 1), but without indentation in the footnotes.
image 1

image 2 with \usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc} activated

\documentclass[10.5pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[width=3.93in, height=6.49in, top=1.0in, papersize={5.5in,8.2in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}

\newfontfamily{\gr}{GFS Porson}
\usepackage{microtype} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{paracol} % needed <<<<<
\parindent=0pt
\newcommand{\mynumber}[1]{%
    \ifnum\value{columnstate}=0
    \marginnote{\footnotesize #1}[0pt] % Nota en el margen izquierdo
    \else
    \marginnote{\footnotesize #1}[0pt] % Nota en el margen derecho
    \fi
}
\newcounter{columnstate}

% Footnotes
%\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

% Shortcuts for any key Greek terms
\newcommand\phantasia{{\gr φαντασία}}
%\hyphenation
\newcommand{\grande}[1]{{\gr \fontsize{11}{14}\selectfont #1}}

    \footnotelayout{m}
    
   \begin{document}

    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \setcolumnwidth{0.40\textwidth/20pt, 0.40\textwidth} % column width + column inter space
    
  \begin{paracol}{2}% 
        
        
        % Configurar el layout de las notas al pie
        %\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0pt}\normalfont}
        
        \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}\selectlanguage{greek}\grande{—Ἐπειδὴ Ἀθήναζε οἴκοθεν ἐκ Κλαζομενῶν\mynumber{126a} ἀφικόμεθα, κατ' ἀγορὰν ἐνετύχομεν Ἀδειμάντῳ τε καὶ Γλαύκωνι· καί μου λαβόμενος τῆς χειρὸς ὁ Ἀδείμαντος, Χαῖρ', ἔφη, ὦ Κέφαλε, καὶ εἴ του δέῃ τῶν τῇδε ὧν ἡμεῖς δυνατοί, φράζε.}\end{otherlanguage}\switchcolumn
        \selectlanguage{spanish}—Cuando llegamos a Atenas desde nuestra Clazómenas\mynumber{126a}, encontramos en el ágora a Adimanto\footnote{\lipsum[1]} y a Glaucón. Adimanto, tomándome la mano, me dijo:Bienvenido, Céfalo, y si hay algo que podamos hacer aquí por ti, dínoslo.\switchcolumn*
        \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}\selectlanguage{greek}\grande{—Ἀλλὰ μὲν δή, εἶπον ἐγώ, πάρειμί γε ἐπ' αὐτὸ τοῦτο, δεησόμενος ὑμῶν.}\end{otherlanguage}\switchcolumn
        \selectlanguage{spanish}—Pues precisamente −contesté− para eso estoy aquí, para pediros un favor.\switchcolumn*
        \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}\selectlanguage{greek}\grande{—Λέγοις ἄν, ἔφη, τὴν δέησιν.}\end{otherlanguage}\switchcolumn
        \selectlanguage{spanish}—Dinos qué te hace falta.\switchcolumn*
        \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}\selectlanguage{greek}\grande{—\mynumber{126b}Καὶ ἐγὼ εἶπον· τῷ ἀδελφῷ ὑμῶν τῷ ὁμομητρίῳ τί ἦν ὄνομα; Οὐ γὰρ μέμνημαι. Παῖς δέ που ἦν, ὅτε τὸ πρότερον ἐπεδήμησα δεῦρο ἐκ Κλαζομενῶν· πολὺς δὲ ἤδη χρόνος ἐξ ἐκείνου. Τῷ μὲν γὰρ πατρί, δοκῶ, Πυριλάμπης ὄνομα.}\end{otherlanguage}\switchcolumn
        \selectlanguage{spanish}—\mynumber{126b}¿Cómo se llamaba vuestro hermano por parte de madre? −pregunté yo entonces−. Pues no lo recuerdo. Era casi un niño cuando vine anteriormente a esta ciudad desde Clazómenas y ya ha pasado mucho tiempo desde entonces. Creo que el nombre de su padre era Pirilampo.\switchcolumn*
        
    \end{paracol} 
    
\end{document}


Do please reveal whether you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Incidentally, 10.5pt is not a valid document class option and is therefore blithely ignored.

I use LuaLaTeX, but I have the same issue with XeLaTeX. It happens the same whether I use 10pt or 11pt.

There is a conflict between paracol and footmisc in that both use \footnotelayout with different definitions.  Footmisc uses it as a hook at the start of every footnote.

Is this what you are trying to achieve?  (I'm still getting errors from the foreigh language stuff.)
\documentclass[10.5pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[width=3.93in, height=6.49in, top=1.0in, papersize={5.5in,8.2in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}

%\newfontfamily{\gr}{GFS Porson}
\usepackage{microtype} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{paracol} % needed <<<<<
\globalcounter*
\footnotelayout{m}

\parindent=0pt
\newcommand{\mynumber}[1]{%
    \ifnum\value{columnstate}=0
    \marginnote{\footnotesize #1}[0pt] % Nota en el margen izquierdo
    \else
    \marginnote{\footnotesize #1}[0pt] % Nota en el margen derecho
    \fi
}
\newcounter{columnstate}


% Footnotes
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

% Shortcuts for any key Greek terms
\newcommand\phantasia{{\gr φαντασία}}
%\hyphenation
\newcommand{\grande}[1]{{\gr \fontsize{11}{14}\selectfont #1}}

    
   \begin{document}

    %\setcounter{footnote}{0}
    %\setcolumnwidth{0.40\textwidth/20pt, 0.40\textwidth} % column width + column inter space
    test\footnote{A footnote slightly longer than one column wide.}
    
  \begin{paracol}{2}% 
        \renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\setlength{\rightskip}{\dimexpr-\columnwidth-\columnsep}}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

        
        % Configurar el layout de las notas al pie
        %\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0pt}\normalfont}
        
        \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}\selectlanguage{greek}\grande{—Ἐπειδὴ Ἀθήναζε οἴκοθεν ἐκ Κλαζομενῶν\mynumber{126a} ἀφικόμεθα, κατ' ἀγορὰν ἐνετύχομεν Ἀδειμάντῳ τε καὶ Γλαύκωνι· καί μου λαβόμενος τῆς χειρὸς ὁ Ἀδείμαντος, Χαῖρ', ἔφη, ὦ Κέφαλε, καὶ εἴ του δέῃ τῶν τῇδε ὧν ἡμεῖς δυνατοί, φράζε.}\end{otherlanguage}\switchcolumn
        \selectlanguage{spanish}—Cuando llegamos a Atenas desde nuestra Clazómenas\mynumber{126a}, encontramos en el ágora a Adimanto\footnote{\lipsum[1]} y a Glaucón. Adimanto, tomándome la mano, me dijo:Bienvenido, Céfalo, y si hay algo que podamos hacer aquí por ti, dínoslo.\switchcolumn*
        \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}\selectlanguage{greek}\grande{—Ἀλλὰ μὲν δή, εἶπον ἐγώ, πάρειμί γε ἐπ' αὐτὸ τοῦτο, δεησόμενος ὑμῶν.}\end{otherlanguage}\switchcolumn
        \selectlanguage{spanish}—Pues precisamente −contesté− para eso estoy aquí, para pediros un favor.\switchcolumn*
        \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}\selectlanguage{greek}\grande{—Λέγοις ἄν, ἔφη, τὴν δέησιν.}\end{otherlanguage}\switchcolumn
        \selectlanguage{spanish}—Dinos qué te hace falta.\switchcolumn*
        \begin{otherlanguage}{greek}\selectlanguage{greek}\grande{—\mynumber{126b}Καὶ ἐγὼ εἶπον· τῷ ἀδελφῷ ὑμῶν τῷ ὁμομητρίῳ τί ἦν ὄνομα; Οὐ γὰρ μέμνημαι. Παῖς δέ που ἦν, ὅτε τὸ πρότερον ἐπεδήμησα δεῦρο ἐκ Κλαζομενῶν· πολὺς δὲ ἤδη χρόνος ἐξ ἐκείνου. Τῷ μὲν γὰρ πατρί, δοκῶ, Πυριλάμπης ὄνομα.}\end{otherlanguage}\switchcolumn
        \selectlanguage{spanish}—\mynumber{126b}¿Cómo se llamaba vuestro hermano por parte de madre? −pregunté yo entonces−. Pues no lo recuerdo. Era casi un niño cuando vine anteriormente a esta ciudad desde Clazómenas y ya ha pasado mucho tiempo desde entonces. Creo que el nombre de su padre era Pirilampo.\switchcolumn*
    
    \end{paracol} 


\end{document}


That's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you very much. If you have any errors due to the language, it's because I installed a special package for Greek GFS Porson
